# Angular unit test a window.open?

Tags: angular, typescript, pruebas-unitarias, karma-jasmine

Tengo un metodo, que cuando se llama habré en una nueva pestaña una pagina. Necesito hacerle unit test, pasa que siempre que llamo al metodo ya en el mismo servidor de karma se abre la pestaña. Hay forma de evitarlo?

Y cual es la forma correcta de testearlo?

**HTML:**

```html
 <button #discordButton class="discord-button-element" (click)="goDiscord()">Go</button>
```

**Typescript**

```js
  goDiscord():void{
    window.open(this.DISCORD_URL, "_blank")    
  }
```

**Unit test:**

```js
  it('goDiscord Is called',() => {
    const discordSpy = spyOn(component, 'goDiscord').and.callThrough();

    component.goDiscord(true)

    expect(discordSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
```

Como les mencione, esto me genera cada vez que recarga el servidor de karma que se abra la pagina ,estoy seguro que no debe ser asi, tiene que haber alguna mejor forma de testearlo.

Por otra parte, tuve que directamente llamar al metodo, ya que no puedo acceder al elemento y simular el click, me devuelve null si lo hago de la siguiente forma

```js
  it('goDiscord Is called',() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const discordSpy = spyOn(component, 'goDiscord').and.callThrough();

    // const button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#discord-button-element')
    const button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#discordButton'));
    button.triggerEventHandler('click',{})

    expect(discordSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
```

**button is null**

Comment: Parece que el selector está incorrecto, si es por CSS se podría seleccionar usando la clase: `By.css('.discord-button-element')`

Comment: @Lobos gracias por comentar, ya probe con la clase y tambien me da null. Pero el hecho es, como hago para testear esto del window.open? y que no se me abra cada vez que inicia karma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de `callThrough` puedes usar `callFake` y pasar una función anónima para ser ejecutada.

```
it('goDiscord Is called', () => {
    const discordSpy = spyOn(component, 'goDiscord').and.callFake(() => console.log('window.open'));

    const button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.discord-button-element'));
    button.triggerEventHandler('click', {})

    expect(discordSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: Me funciono gracias. 
Lo que no me funciona es el tema del trigger, como que no me deja acceder al button del html, me da null. Porque puede ser?